# VSCode Hangs on breakpoint when attached to remote debugger on a windows docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, .net-core, remote-debugging, docker-for-windows

When attaching the VSDB.exe vs code clr remote debugger to a dotnet running process in a windows docker container in VSCode, the applications goes into debug mode and retrieves a list of threads and shows the debug output, but when I hit a breakpoint, VS Code hangs and stopping debugging shuts down the docker container. Using the same debugger works fine locally. Is this a problem in Docker or VSCode?

Docker info

```
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 15063 (15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise N
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 39
 System Time: 2017-07-19T12:13:06.0721766-07:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I've included debugger output logs from local debug and remote debug below

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build 
COPY ./tools/coreclr-debug-win7-x64 ./debug/coreclr-debug

COPY ./Clients/Client.Web.Identity.Client.MVC ./Clients/Client.Web.Identity.Client.MVC

WORKDIR ./Clients/Client.Web.Identity.Client.MVC
RUN dotnet restore Client.MVC.csproj
RUN dotnet build Client.MVC.csproj
```

Running the image:

```
docker run -d idsrv4-mvc-dev-src dotnet run http://*:60720
```

Remote debug task

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Remote Attach",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeProgram": "powershell",
        "pipeArgs": ["docker exec -i heuristic_goodall" ],
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debuggerPath": "c:\\debug\\coreclr-debug\\vsdbg.exe"
    },
    "processId": "1816"
},
```

Local debug task in Launch.json

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Local Attach Using Explicit Debugger",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
    "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeProgram": "powershell",
        "pipeArgs": [],
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debuggerPath": "C:\\tools\\coreclr-debug-win7-x64\\vsdbg.exe"
    }
}
```

Logs from debugging remotely
https://pastebin.com/kxV7MMRA

Logs from debugging locally
https://pastebin.com/7gX6tZQ6